# Pull DHCP Client Lease Logs from txt file into Event Viewer Server 2012

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 2012 R2 box that collects client lease logs in a text file in \system32\dhcp whihc is pretty standard stuff.

However, I need to get that text file into Event Viewer so that it can br forwarded onto another system.

Is anyone aware of a way to pull the data out of that text file and move it into the DHCP Event viwer, either into an existing event or into its a new event.

I'm thinking maybe Powershell could do it, perhaps using New-EventLog or similar.

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok so I've got it workin the way I want but now I need to change the event ID depending on the first two numbers of each line in the log file. SO teh log files start like this....

00....this is blah blah blah

22....this is blah blah blah

25....this is blah blah blah

24....this is blah blah blah

44....this is blah blah blah

67....this is blah blah blah

What I've got wotking is ....

Get-Content C:\Users\ma\Desktop\lines.txt | Foreach-Object {Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "lines" -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message " $_ "}

SO for example if the beginning of the line is 00.... then the EventID needs to also be 00

Comment: Can You share sample text file

Comment: You can use combination of get-content and write-eventlog to achieve ,but seeing sample data helps